# UISearchBar not working with sub sections in array

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

I am using an array variable called sections as the table view has collapsable sections:

```
var sections = [

        // TESTING CODE FOR SECTIONS
        Section(sec: "One",
                subSec: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
                expanded: false),

        Section(sec: "Two",
                subSec: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
                expanded: false),

        Section(sec: "Three",
                subSec: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
                expanded: false),
```

I am trying to use UISearchController to make the table view searchable. Here is what I have tried so far but its not working:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
  filtered = sections.filter({( section : Section) -> Bool in
    return section.subSec.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
  })

  tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I understand how the function works but cannot seem to get it to work with my subSec in the variable.

```
//SEARCH
    var filteredSections: [String]?
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //SEARCH
        filteredSections = sections
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    }
```

I get errors such as 'cannot assign value of type '[Section]' to type '[String]?' I understand why, but I don't know how to resolve this.

Section definition:

```
struct Section {
    var sec: String!
    var subSec: [String]! // [ ] = Array of Strings
    var expanded: Bool!

    init(sec: String, subSec: [String], expanded: Bool) {
        self.sec = sec
        self.subSec = subSec
        self.expanded = expanded
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you actually want to return? `filteredSections` is an array of Strings, while `sections` is an array of `Sections`, so `filteredSections = sections` obviously won't work. Do you want to return an array of sections or Strings?

Comment: I want to be able to return the names of the subSec if they match the search string. i.e if a user types 'A' in the search field, it would only show 'A' in the tableView. It works with a normal array of strings, but not the way I have used the sections variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filteredSections` is an array of Strings and you are trying to assign the output of a filter function called on an array of `Section`s, which return an array of `Section`s, so it obviously won't work.

If you want to return `String`s as a result of filtering the array of `Section`s, you need to combine `filter` and `map`, which can be done with a single `flatMap`.

The ternary operator inside the flatMap checks the same condition as your filter did, but it returns `section.subSec.name` if the condition evaluates to true and `nil` otherwise, which the `flatMap` simply ignores, hence the output array will only contain the matching subsection names.

```
func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
  filtered = sections.flatMap{ return $0.subSec.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) ? searchText : nil }

  tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Since you didn't include the definition of `Section` in your code, I couldn't test the function, but if `subSec.name` is a `String`, it will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help! subSec.name isn't possible as subSec does not have a member 'name'

Comment: To the view controller where your `tableView` is defined.

Comment: Btw where is `subSec.name` coming from in your code, it is not defined anywhere?

Comment: Your right, it isn't. How would I change this to fit? If I remove .name it shows an error: `Value of type [String] has no member lowercased` I added my Sections definition

Comment: This is the only error I am getting now, everything else seems great.

Comment: `subSec` is an array of Strings, which you check whether it contains the `searchText` or not. What do you want to return from this?

Comment: Ideally the string that matches the search string. subSec contains an array of strings "A", "B"... If a user searches for "A" I want it to return all "A"

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Why would you want to return the exact string that was searched for without any more context? If the search string was a substring and you would want to return all strings containing that substring, that would make sense. But returning the same string several times doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: That was a bad example. The letters don't really need to be A B C, they could be any string.

Comment: But still, you want to display the exact same string several times? Updated my answer anyways, the current code would return the `searchText` if it was found in the `subSec` and `nil` otherwise, meaning that `filtered` will contain `searchText` as many times as it was found.